# nGINX read Header & Pass it to different Application Server

Tags: nginx, http-headers, uwsgi

I have an nGINX server running. I want to read custom HTTP Header from the incoming Request and redirect it to different application server. I did search for similar questions but found for writing custom headers but not how to read..

if a header is set with this -> "version = Version 1.0" then it should redirect different application (say uwsgi_pass x.x.x.x:80)

if it is set as "version = Version 2.0" then it should redirect to (uwsgi_pass x.x.x.x:99)

I tried in my nginx.conf file

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name xyz.com;

        if ($http_version ~ 'Version 1.0') {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.116:99/calc;
        }

        if ($http_version ~ 'Version 2.0') {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.116:99;
        }


    location /hello {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.116:99/calc;
            }

        }
```

I'm getting error when I restart my nGINX

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:19
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you set a custom header in this form:

```
version: Version 1.0
```

Then you can configure nginx like in this way:

```
location / {
    if ($http_version ~ 'Version 1.0') {
        uwsgi_pass localhost:8888;
    }

    if ($http_version ~ 'Version 2.0') {
        uwsgi_pass localhost:9999;
    }
}
```

Reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24http_HEADER

Comment: @Kartik proxy_pass/uwsgi_pass directives is only allowed in location context. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. I did try it yesterday but was givin an error. but today it worked.. :) Thanks.. Although I havent checked whether it actually passes a request.. ;)

Comment: It says
nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "192.168.0.116:8888" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:24